# porque mostra essa mensagem no inspecionar elementos quando estou fazendo a conexo com o banco de dados e o asp

Tags: sql, asp

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'
>
> The name "rafeel@emtu.net" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
>
> /aplicativos/JSON_UTIL_0.1.1.asp, line 5

Comment: Sem você postar seu comando fica difícil ajuda-lo. Certamente existe um erro de sintaxe nele.

Comment: Adicione o código da linha 5 desse arquivo `JSON_UTIL_0.1.1.asp` na sua pergunta.

Comment: Tá com cara de faltar aspas no comando. Mas só dá pra ter certeza vendo o código que está tentando executar.

Answer (score 0):

Isso pode dever-se a diferentes situações sendo as mais comuns quando tentamos utilizar uma coluna como DEFAULT value de outra coluna na criação de uma tabela. Apenas é possível utilziar constantes, scalar functions ou NULL.

Também pode dever-se a erros de sintaxe, aspas a mais, não incluir o '@' nos parâmetros de uma query, etc.